# При наведении на чекбокс цвет не меняется

Tags: html, css

```
<https://codepen.io/terema001/pen/wvMdrEX?editors=1100>

Код вот . В чем может быть ошибка ?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        
        <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

    </body>
</html>





ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li::before {   
    content: '';   
    display: inline-block;   
    height: 35px;   
    width: 35px;    
    background-size: 35px;   
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTkvqlB1RcYy_SSh2kNprhTEKb0uH0wMiqx8Q&usqp=CAU');   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-position: center center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
}

ul li:hover:before{
    background-color:red;
    
}


[описание][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/terema001/pen/wvMdrEX?editors=1100
```

Comment: `ul li:hover:before { background-color:red; background-image: none; }` — цвет меняется, но картинка закрывает его. Она не прозрачная.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `background-color` имел меньший приоритет чем свойство `background-image`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        
        <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

    </body>
</html>





ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li::before {   
    content: '';   
    display: inline-block;   
    height: 35px;   
    width: 35px;    
    background-size: 35px;   
    background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTkvqlB1RcYy_SSh2kNprhTEKb0uH0wMiqx8Q&usqp=CAU') no-repeat center center;   
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
}

ul li:hover:before{
    background: red;
    
}
```

Comment: цвет на белый меняется а не на красный

Comment: Еще раз проверьте

Comment: что тогда использовать вместо background- color ?

Comment: Просто свойство background, я в ответе написал

Comment: не работает чето

Comment: https://codepen.io/nord18/pen/xxZdPYL

Comment: а как сделать чтоб чекбокс менял картинку ?